# Wordpress media manager > Force image overwrite?

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a setting or filter that I can set in my functions.php file that will force the wordpress media manager to overwrite images that are uploaded with the exact same filename as an image that already resides in the uploads folder?

Currently, it creates duplicates of images with the same filename, and just adds a number to the end of the newly uploaded image.

Comment: Hmm, quite like the sound of this - will look into it :)

Comment: Sounds good TDM, Any progress on this?

Answer (score 1):

I just released a plugin called [Overwrite Uploads](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/overwrite-uploads/) that lets you do this.

Comment: but it requires editing a core file. not optimal, but thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I agree. WP doesn't have the hook necessary to do it directly. I've added a Trac ticket to have it added, but it's been ignored. I'm thinking about working around it in a future version so that it doesn't need to modify the core, but I'm not sure when I'll have time to finish it.